# Weird characters while reading file content

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

I'm not sure what is wrong:

```
for line in open(textfile, 'r'):
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
ï»¿abcd
```

The file was created using textpad++ using Unix EOL and UTF8 encoding.

Now it works properly using Encoding with UTF-8 without BOM option on notepad++ . But why? I mean how could I convert all sent files to UTF-8 to avoid weird chars?

Comment: Microsoft and their love for the UTF-8 BOM..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Specifying [encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) will solve your problem.

```
for line in open(textfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig'):
    print(line)
```

[`utf_8_sig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#module-encodings.utf_8_sig): UTF-8 codec with BOM signature

Comment: Worked as a charm :). I'm marking this as soon i arrive at home.

Answer (score 2):

You must set the encoding of your file while reading it, using UTF-8.

Add a third parameter to your code, setting its enconding. From:

```
for line in open(textfile, 'r'):
    print(line)
```

to:

```
for line in open(textfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig'):
    print (line)
```