# Python can't read log file correctly unless I paste its content in a new text file

Tags: python

I am using open() to read a log file, but I got strange content. If I open the log file by Notepad++, copy the content and paste it in new file, save it as .txt file, open() can read the correct content.
Code is:

```
with open(a_file, 'r') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        line_number += 1
        if line_number == 1060 or line_number == 1061:
            print(line)
```

I tried many methods:

1. cat the log file and redirect to a new text file, no help
2. Open the log file in Notepad++, save as... a new text file, no help
3. Use linux tail command, redirect the output to a new text file, no help
4. Use python codecs to read it as utf-8, error happen "python codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte"
5. Open the log file in Notepad++, copy its content, paste in a new file, save to a new text file, it works.

Comment: How was the log file created?

Comment: post the content of logfile

Comment: @saulspatz I don't know exactly how it was created, I guess it was created by some trace decode tool. Now I found that if I split them into small file, only the first split (xaa) can be display by vim, the others can't be display correctly.

Comment: @vks if I open the split xab by vim, lines are like: ^@ ^@ ^@ ^@ ^@s^@e^@r^@v^@i^@c^@e^@R^@e^@q^@u^@e^@s^@t^@ ^@{^@^M^@

Comment: are you using python 2 or 3? have you tried using `open('a_file', 'rt')` or `open('a_file', 'rb')` ??

Comment: @markjay I am using python 3.5. I didn't specify t or b, i just used open('a_file', 'r'). I think the file itself has problem, as if I split it, the later split can't be displayed by vim correctly.

Comment: maybe it's the encoding. have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918120/weird-characters-while-reading-file-content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't read the file because the it's encoded in `UTF-16`, you can tell by the first characters which are the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). `0xff` is part of the BOM for `UTF-16`. So when reading just add `encoding='utf16'` (or use `codecs.open` with `utf16` in python2)